# Show that composition of endomorphisms share some eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\psi$ and $\varphi$ be endomorphisms such that $\psi$ $\circ$ $\varphi$ = $\varphi$ $\circ$ $\psi$ over some algebraically closed field. Show that they share an eigenvector.

It seemed quite straightforward at first but the more time I thought about it the more difficult it seemed... My last bet is to assume there are two eigenvectors, put them into matrix of Jordan form and show that one of them finally disappears (once you take subsequent compositions) which would lead to contradiction. Still I'm not sure whether it would be legal and sufficient for a proof so I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

We proceed by induction on the dimension, with the one-dimensional case being trivial.

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $\varphi$ with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

We compute $\lambda \psi(v) = \psi(\varphi(v))=\varphi(\psi(v))$, hence we deduce that $\psi(v)$ is also an eigenvector of $\varphi$ with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

We conclude: $\ker(\varphi - \lambda)$ is an invariant subspace with respect to both $\varphi$ (a priori clear) and $\psi$ (shown in the previous computation).

So we can restrict to $\ker(\varphi - \lambda)$ and use induction. Note that we can assume $\ker(\varphi - \lambda)$ to be a proper subspace, because the assertion is trivial if $\ker(\varphi - \lambda)$ is the whole vectorspace.

Comment: Thanks MooS. Could you explain how you conclude that ker(.) is invariant? Maybe it would help me to understand implication cause I don't get how it is helpful :(

Comment: With respect to which map?